# Python: Facebook API showing invalid token

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using [facepy facebook graph API](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy) to access my mailbox/messages and I followed the following two approaches:

**1st Approach:**

I used the `access token` I got from `Graph Explorer` facebook page and use the below code:

```
from facepy import GraphAPI
graph = GraphAPI(token)
print graph.get('/me')
#Rest of the code
```

The above code worked fine and I was able to retrieve all my messages using an `FQL Query`. The problem arised when my auth_token `expired` after sometime.

So, after some googling I shifted to **approach two**:

Now, what I did was created a facebook app gave it `read_mailbox` permission and got it's `id and key` and then used [get_application_access_token](https://facepy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/utilities.html#facepy.utils.get_application_access_token) method of facepy to get the token.

After retrieving the token I used:

```
token = facepy.utils.get_application_access_token(app_id, key)
graph.get('/me')
## OUT: OAuthError: [2500] An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
facepy.utils.get_extended_access_token(token, app_id, key)
# OUT: OAuthError: [1] No user access token specified
```

Now, you can see the error(`commented #`) generated on using the application token.

I believe the error I am getting is because facebook needs the `user_token` and I am supplying it with `app_token`.

So, is it possible to access user data using the app_token and if not how can one issue a `extended token` which can access user data.

**Update:**

So, I followed @Johannes suggestion and tried this but ran into error:

```
from facepy.utils import get_extended_access_token
from facepy import GraphAPI
token = "My user access token got from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer"
long_lived_access_token = get_extended_access_token(token)
graph = GraphAPI(long_lived_access_token)
graph.get('/me')
```

Now, when I ran the above code I got

```
TypeError: get_extended_access_token() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

So, I changed it to `long_lived_access_token = get_extended_access_token(token, None, None)` and got

```
facepy.exceptions.OAuthError
```

So, I again I changed it to `long_lived_access_token = get_extended_access_token(token, app_id, key)` and I got the same exception/error as above.

So, is this a bug or am I doing something wrong.

PS: I installed the latest version from git.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right in your assumption that you cannot use application access tokens to read a user's mailbox, but the error you're getting stems from the fact that you haven't initialized `graph` with an access token at all.

Be that as it may, you're on the right track in asking for how you can extend the user's access token. As you have already discovered, Facepy HEAD (soon to be version 0.9) has a function `get_extended_access_token` which accepts an existing short-lived user access token and extends it. Extended user access tokens last for 2 months, and you can read more about them in Facebook's documentation on the [removal of offline_access permission](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/).

If you want to use `get_extended_access_token` right now, you will have to install facepy from git:

```
$ pip install git+git://github.com/jgorset/facepy.git@b5153f460f2f52cef9a5e49a3b48b3fb8742356c
```

Once you've installed the right version of Facepy, you can extend an existing short-lived user access token and initialize a new instance of `GraphAPI` with it:

```
from facepy.utils import get_extended_access_token
from facepy import GraphAPI

long_lived_access_token, expires_at = get_extended_access_token(short_lived_access_token, application_id, application_secret_key)

graph = GraphAPI(long_lived_access_token)
graph.get('/me')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion/answer. Please have a look at my `updated` question.

Comment: In your API `get_extended_access_token` returns a tuple so the correct way to pass token will be `graph = GraphAPI(long_lived_access_token[0])`.

Comment: @RanRag: You're right. I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: @JohannesGorset, is it still working? I keep getting error or invalid access token from it.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with the API you are just not interpreting the result in a right way. 
If you try to print the result of `long_lived_access_token = get_extended_access_token(token)` it will not directly give you a `long_lived_access_token` instead it will provide you a tuple with contents:

```
long_lived_access_token = ('your token', datetime_object).
```

You can verify this by looking at the source code of [utils.py](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy/blob/master/facepy/utils.py). If you look at `get_extended_access_token` method it returns `token, expires_at`.

According to the [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) to get the `extended` access token one has to make request at the below endpoint

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

and the response is something like `token=mytoken&expire=5184000` where `5184000` means 60 days.

So, your final code will look something like:

```
from facepy.utils import get_extended_access_token
from facepy import GraphAPI

app_id = 'id'
key = 'key'

short_lived_access_token = 'short_token'
long_token = get_extended_access_token(short_token, id, key)

graph = GraphAPI(long_token[0])
print graph.get('/me')
```

Comment: Thanks, it wokrked perfectly but am confused on which answer to accept.

Comment: @Noob: Glad to hear that. I believe you should accept `Johannes` answer because he is the original author of the API and what I did is just looked up his `API docs`. So, the credit must go to the author not me.