# Facebook: How to get/update user access token using python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently am using `Graph Explorer` to get a short-lived user access token and than converting it to a `extended token(60 days)` by a call to [facepy get_extended_access_token](https://facepy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/utilities.html#facepy.utils.get_extended_access_token) method.

Now. consider the scenario where my user access token becomes invalid because of either user logging out or the token expires itself. So, in both the cases I need to get a new user access token because `get_extended_access_token` requires `access_token` so that it can extend it.

So, my question is how to retrieve this token using python? Is there any particular url which I can send a request and it will return a new/updated token in resonse.

**Update**:

So, after following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058723/programmatically-getting-an-access-token-for-using-the-facebook-graph-api) and making a request to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxx&client_secret=yyyy&grant_type=client_credentials
```

I got this token which I believe is an `app access token`

```
access_token=123456789|12abcdef234 #changed from original
```

But what I need is an user access token through which I can read my mailbox.

Comment: Maybe these will come in handy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058723/programmatically-getting-an-access-token-for-using-the-facebook-graph-api

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676634/python-facebook-api-showing-invalid-token

Answer (score 1):

If the access token has expired or been invalidated you need to go back through the Auth Dialog, i.e. a user must manually re-grant access to your application. Retrieving it programmatically defeats the whole purpose of token invalidation/expiry.

Once you get this token, you can then use `get_extended_access_token` to get the long lived one

App tokens can be used to publish a post on the user's behalf.

Comment: Sorry for sounding noobish but what exactly do you mean by `go back through the Auth Dialog` because currently what I am doing is get an access token from `graph explorer` than use `get_extended_access_token` to get a new token and using that token run a `FQL query`. So, you can see no where there is need to grant access to the application. The only reason I had to create an application is to `app id and secret` to get a extended token.

Comment: @Noob no it cannot be used for that. Auth Dialog can be invoked via https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&scope=PERMISSIONS&response_type=token which is what the Graph API Explorer sends you every time you add a new permission in the tool

Comment: So, on using the above url with `redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html` I get a success page having a `valid` user token in the page url. Now, is the above procedure possible using python because I believe one has to be logged in on facebook to do that.

Comment: SO, the solution I came up for this is invoke the browser with the above url and ask the user to copy the access_token and paste it in a config file.